# Which version of Bing API uses OpenLayers? (if any)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, openlayers, bing-api

I am developing a web applicatione that makes use of Open Layer version 3.20.

I have read that Microsoft recently released the new Bing Maps API version 8 deprecating previous versions.

Is there any relation between the Bing Maps API version and the Open Layers version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no relation. OpenLayers only uses the Imagery API from the Bing Maps REST Services to get imagery metadata, like the required attributions and available resolutions for the tiles. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701721.aspx.